# encoding/decoding strings in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have a function that returns a utf-16 encoded string and I have to include its result into another string by a replace:

```
string = myfunc()

debug_string = debug_string.replace("$rep$", string)
```

In my eclipse environment it works fine, but in another environment it gives an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Do you know what is the possible cause?

Thanks

Comment: What is the other environment? And is that the actual code that produces the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your `string` variable isn't in Unicode? Then you need to explicitly decode sequence of bytes (in UTF-16 encoding) from `string` (string type) to Unicode object:

```
u_string = myfunc().decode('utf-16')
```

`debug_string` also should be in Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string = myfunc()

debug_string = debug_string.replace("$rep$", string).encode('utf-16')
```

Or:

```
string = myfunc()

debug_string = debug_string.replace("$rep$", string).decode('utf-16')
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, work with unicodes all the way. If you can't change `myfunc`, at least convert its result to unicode:

```
string = myfunc().decode('utf-16')
```

If your `debug_string` is already unicode, it should not be necessary to change anything else. Otherwise decode it as well using the appropriate codec.